# Running JDK between Tomcat Server and project

Tags: java

Uhm, I had a question and i want to ask you. I build project using jdk 1.6 and my tomcat server using jdk 1.8 so when we running project in tomcat server, what is the jdk are running??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question are little bit confusing so you can edit or go for these that i learn your question and try to resolve it.

No its need to configure with jdk 1.8 without its configure it can two possibilities.

1. Or you select same jdk version jdk 1.6
2. Or you can configure jdk 1.8

-> You can read this article for better jdk compatibility (Kinds of Compatibility) 
http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~darcy/OpenJdkDevGuide/OpenJdkDevelopersGuide.v0.777.html#compatibility

Answer (score 0):

The one on the tomcat server; jdk 1.8 is the runtime. Java is almost universally capable of running software compiled on an older compiler. The reverse is also true with special command switches to the compiler (as long as new language features and classes are also not used). There is also the property `java.version` which you can read to determine this at runtime. Like,

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
```